# Unable to find the sub menu element which disappears when mouse pointer is moved outside the menu frame

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, submenu

My code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fmf-name-title-cellsort-label']")).click(); // Main menu item
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='quick-filter-input']")).sendKeys("Profile1121"); // Sub menu item
```

In above code:

Sub menu item disappears when moves is moved out, and unable to find the element "@id='quick-filter-input"

Error displayed:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='quick-filter-input']"}
Command duration or timeout: 10.02 seconds
```

SubMenu appears when main menu is clicked.

Could some one help me out here, how to find that required subMenu element?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a dropdown which appears only at hover you must use:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(menu)); //this makes your submenu appear
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(submenu)).click().perform(); //this click your submenu or you can do whatever action you want with it
```